# ImportError: Could not import settings

Tags: django, python-2.7

On Windows 8, I've created a sample project in Django (1.6.5) and I'm getting errors when I run a custom command I wrote (runtcpserver).

This is how my project structure looks like:

c:/django/entitetracker:

```
manage.py

tcpserver/
    forms.py
    views.py
    models.py
    urls.py
    management
       __init__.py
       command
           __init__.py
           runtcpserver.py

settings/
    __init__.py
    base.py
    local.py
```

My manage.py file is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "entitetracker.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

My path (python 2.7):

```
>>> import sys
>>> for path in sys.path: print path
C:\django\entitetracker
(...other paths)
```

When I run the python manage.py runtcpserver settings=settings.local command, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
commands = get_commands()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
% (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'entitetracker.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named settings
```

In python shell, I tried to import the settings module and I'm getting no error:

```
>>> from settings import local
>>>
```

Could someone suggest what I am missing?

Comment: __init__ is empty, local import everything from base. I found my error (see below). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your `PYTHONPATH` is `C:\django\entitetracker`. You can load `entitetracker.settings`. In finish, Python try to find `C:\django\entitetracker\entitetracker\settings` package.

Use

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
```

Comment: It "seems" to work (actually I'm getting another error - SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty but this is probably another story). Could I alternatively set PYTHONPATH to c:\django and setdefault to "entitetracker.settings"? I tried it but it does not work. I ask the question because the same project in Ubuntu has entitetracker.settings and it works fine.

Comment: the SECRET_KEY error seems to be related to my original problem. I've read elsewhere that it looks like DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is not being loaded correctly. So it's not clear if your solution is the good one. P.S. I does have a SECRET_KEY variable defined in my settings file local.py

Answer (score 0):

My God, I'm so stupid. The error was I was missing the two dashes before settings=settings.local! Thanks for your help Tomasz.